# heroku review apps: deploying docker container

Tags: docker, heroku, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to create review apps for my open source application which already has a docker file.Is there any way where I could write an app.json file to deploy a Docker container for new pull requests for review apps?
or is there any way to use heroku container registry and runtime in review apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using heroku's new [build manifest](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-yml-build-manifest), you can use the Build API to deploy your docker apps.
This means you can use `git push` to build a docker app. You can also use GitHub Sync, and Review Apps.

Comment: atleast is there any build pack that could run docker on heroku?

Comment: Nope. Docker requires sudo to run, and heroku slugs don't have sudo.